# Is there a way to create a UDF that accepts an array of two strings and pass those strings as two arguments to a function?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm new to Scala so pardon my poor penmanship.
I have a function func1 that accepts two strings and returns a string.
I also have a dataframe df1 that has 2 columns a1 and b1. I'm trying to create a new dataframe df2 with both the columns from df1 (a1 and b1) and a new column c1 that is the output of the function func1. I know I need to use UDF. I don't know how to create a UDF that can accept 2 columns and pass these two as parameters to func1 and return the output string (column c1).

Here's some of the things that I tried -

```
def func1(str1:String, str2:String) : String = {   
        //code
        return str3;
}

val df1= spark.sql("select * from emp")
  .select("a1", "b1").cache()


val df2 = spark.sql("select * from df1")
  .withColumn("c1", func1("a1","b1"))
  .select("a1", "b1").cache()
```

But I don't get the results. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have a syntax problem.

Remember that when you do `def func1(str1:String, str2:String) : String = ...` func1 refers to a Scala function object, and not a Spark expression.

On the other hand, `.withColumn` expects a Spark expression as its second argument.

So what happens is that your call to `.withColumn("c1", func1("a1","b1"))` sends Spark a Scala `function` object, whereas the Spark API expects a "Spark Expression" (e.g. a column, or operation on columns, such as a User Defined Function (UDF)).

Luckily, it is easy to transform a Scala function into a Spark UDF, generally speaking, by wrapping it by a call to spark's `udf` method.

So a working example can go out like this :

```
// A sample dataframe 
val dataframe = Seq(("a", "b"), ("c", "d")).toDF("columnA", "columnB")
// An example scala function that actually does something (string concat)
def concat(first: String, second: String) = first+second
// A conversion from scala function to spark UDF :
val concatUDF = udf((first: String, second: String) => concat(first, second))
// An sample execution of the UDF
// note the $ sign, which is short for indicating a column name
dataframe.withColumn("concat", concatUDF($"columnA", $"columnB")).show
+-------+-------+------+
|columnA|columnB|concat|
+-------+-------+------+
|      a|      b|    ab|
|      c|      d|    cd|
+-------+-------+------+
```

From there on, it should be easy to adapt to your precise function and its arguments.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your rudimentary explanations. Helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how, you would do it

```
scala> val df = Seq(("John","26"),("Bob","31")).toDF("a1","b1")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a1: string, b1: string]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("emp")

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def func1(str1:String, str2:String) : String = {
        val str3 = s" ${str1} is ${str2} years old"
        return str3;
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

func1: (str1: String, str2: String)String

scala> val my_udf_func1 = udf( func1(_:String,_:String):String )
my_udf_func1: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,StringType,Some(List(StringType, StringType)))

scala> spark.sql("select * from emp").withColumn("c1", my_udf_func1($"a1",$"b1")).show(false)
2019-01-14 21:08:30 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
+----+---+---------------------+
|a1  |b1 |c1                   |
+----+---+---------------------+
|John|26 | John is 26 years old|
|Bob |31 | Bob is 31 years old |
+----+---+---------------------+


scala>
```

Two places where you need to correct it..

After defining the regular function, you need to register it in udf() as

`val my_udf_func1 = udf( func1(_:String,_:String):String )`

when calling the udf you should use `$"a1"` syntax, not simply `"a1"`

Comment: This is very helpful as well. Thank you!